WPF SwitchToMainThreadAsync and main thread re-entrancy
Below is a C# snippet in WPF, after executing MethodTest, is the content of _listTest determinant to be [1, 2, 3]?
Could it be that in edge cases, before Method2() executes, Method3() finishes, resulting in [1, 3, 2]?
Note: ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync is from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.
private List<int> _listTest  = new List<int>();

private void MethodTest()
{
    // suppose we are on UI thread (Main Thread)
    _listTest.Clear();
    Method1();
    var task3 = Method3();  // async method
    Method2();
}

private void Method1()
{
    _listTest.Add(1);
}

private void Method2()
{
    _listTest.Add(2);
}

private async Task Method3() {
    await TaskScheduler.Default;
    await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();
    _listTest.Add(3);
}


You should await Method3. Not doing so could be considered a bug.

@Clemens I edited the question and add var task = .... This question want to discuss main thread re-entrancy, so not awaiting Method3 is deliberately.

Of course, when you just start a task without awaiting, code proceeds immediately to next line, in your case you do not await Method3 call, so Method2 will be executed as soon as first await is hit and execution will be yielded back to the caller.
So, you are correct, in some cases there might be that Method3 finishes before Method2.
Example:
consider below example, which is your code, slightly modified:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace console
{
    internal class NotTrulyAsync
    {
        private List<int> _listTest = new List<int>();

        public bool Assert()
        {
            return _listTest.SequenceEqual([1, 2, 3]);
        }

        public async Task MethodTest()
        {
            _listTest.Clear();
            Method1();
            var t = Method3();  // async method
            Method2();

            await t;
        }

        private void Method1()
        {
            _listTest.Add(1);
        }

        private void Method2()
        {
            _listTest.Add(2);
        }

        private async Task Method3()
        {
            await AsyncMethod();
            _listTest.Add(3);
        }

        private async Task AsyncMethod()
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    internal class TrulyAsync
    {
        private List<int> _listTest = new List<int>();

        public bool Assert()
        {
            return _listTest.SequenceEqual([1, 2, 3]);
        }

        public async Task MethodTest()
        {
            _listTest.Clear();
            Method1();
            var t = Method3();  // async method
            Method2();

            await t;
        }

        private void Method1()
        {
            _listTest.Add(1);
        }

        private void Method2()
        {
            _listTest.Add(2);
        }

        private async Task Method3()
        {
            await AsyncMethod();
            _listTest.Add(3);
        }

        private async Task AsyncMethod()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }
    }
}

When Method3 is "truly async", then you will get expected result, if it represents task already finished, 3 will come before 2.
I have made test, and 100% cases in above truly async example were correct, while none of "non truly async" results were correct.

"in some cases there might be that Method3 finishes before Method2", in my original code, is this case possible?

Yes, if what you arę await will happen to be truły asynchronous, but i think so
